# Any values of 0 or 1 from REST API, when type-casted to boolean returns true

Tags: javascript, boolean

I came across a strange issue with boolean operation in my web application. I have a service that responds with `1` and `0` for `true` and `false`. The REST API (internal one) that I call, sends only this output:

```
GET /stuff/id/5
0
```

```
GET /stuff/id/7
1
```

Based on the above output from the server, I use a toggle switch in the front end to check make it switch on or off. The code that makes it is:

```
$(this).find(".toggle").toggles({
  "on": requestContent
});
```

I do understand that sometimes, `1` and `0` might not be interpreted as boolean true or false, so I planned to use `!!` to force them to get converted into `true` and `false`.

```
$(this).find(".toggle").toggles({
  "on": !!requestContent
});
```

But still, to my dismay, it shows all the switches in the **ON** position, than the right way. Somehow it is getting converted to only `true` for both the values of `1` and `0`.

I have even tried to make a mock version of the server call and my front end here, which exactly replicates the issue:

```js
$(function () {
  // Mimicking the HTTP Response.
  var states = ["1", "0", "0", "1", "1"];
  // This loop loops through all the values and sets the state of the switch.
  $('.toggle').each(function (i) {
    $(this).toggles({
      "on": !!states[i]
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
ul {width: 150px; margin: auto; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #eee;}
ul li {padding: 10px;}
ul li span,
ul li .toggle {width: 50px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
ul li span {width: 75px; line-height: 1;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles/master/css/toggles-full.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles/master/toggles.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 4</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 5</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, all the happens is even `!!0` returns `true`. How do I solve this? What's the mystery behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the way JavaScript type-casts is totally different. In other words, after an hour of debugging, I found that the issue was with the way JavaScript treats the strings as *truthy values*.

When the server responds, the response is always given as `string` type. Strings with a `0` (which is actually `"0"`) need to be type-casted into boolean `false`. Instead, JavaScript takes it as a **non-empty `string`** and finds it as truthy value.

Let's consider this code that I ran on the console.

```
» if ("0") "Yes"; else "No";
« "Yes"
```

Here, we could clearly see that the `"0"` string value is treated as a `true` or correctly, *truthy* value. So when the non-empty strings are not considered as `false`, a string with `"0"` is also not considered `false`.

**Work-arounds**

One of the best way to get around this is using the comparison with `0`. Consider the following instruction on the console:

```
» "0" == 0
« true
```

```
» !!"0"
« true
```

To check the correct value, the comparison operator helps us in comparing string `"0"` with integral `0` and it works. At the same time, it is freaking out that the type-casting of string `"0"` gives you `true`.

The second method would be using `parseInt()`. This should be used only when we are triple sure that the output is an integral value and nothing else. We can also add `isNaN()` as an exception handling mechanism, but that would be overkill.

```
» if (parseInt("0")) "Yes"; else "No";
« "No"
```

**Solution**

Right now, the best solution is to use `parseInt()`, as I am definitely sure the service will not return any other value other than `1` or `0`.

```js
$(function () {
  // Mimicking the HTTP Response.
  var states = ["1", "0", "0", "1", "1"];
  // This loop loops through all the values and sets the state of the switch.
  $('.toggle').each(function (i) {
    $(this).toggles({
      // Now this works perfectly! ;)
      "on": parseInt(states[i])
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
ul {width: 150px; margin: auto; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #eee;}
ul li {padding: 10px;}
ul li span,
ul li .toggle {width: 50px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
ul li span {width: 75px; line-height: 1;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles/master/css/toggles-full.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/simontabor/jquery-toggles/master/toggles.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 4</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 5</span>
    <div class="toggle toggle-light"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have asked and answered my own question. If anyone has a better explanation (with sources), or a different work-around, please post another answer.

Comment: Nice and good explanation